# Can't find an Entry Point 'GetDeviceUniqueID' in a PInvoke DLL 'coredll.dll'

Tags: c#

Newish to Porgramming,
I have a project which needs a unique device id for each mobile device, done in C#.

Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK R2

Heres the code piece I'm working with:

```
    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    private extern static int GetDeviceUniqueID([In, Out] byte[] appdata,
                                                int cbApplictionData,
                                                int dwDeviceIDVersion,
                                                [In, Out] byte[] deviceIDOuput,
                                                out uint pcbDeviceIDOutput);



    public static string GetDeviceID()
    {
        string appString = "MyApplication";
        byte[] appData = new byte[appString.Length];
        for (int count = 0; count < appString.Length; count++)
        {
            appData[count] = (byte)appString[count];
        }

        int appDataSize = appData.Length;
        byte[] DeviceOutput = new byte[20];
        uint SizeOut = 20;
        GetDeviceUniqueID(appData, appDataSize, 1, DeviceOutput, out SizeOut);

        string idString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < DeviceOutput.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 8 || i == 10)
                idString = String.Format("{0}-{1}", idString, DeviceOutput[i].ToString("x2"));
            else
                idString = String.Format("{0}{1}", idString, DeviceOutput[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
        return idString;


    }
```

But when i try deploy and run i get:
Can't find an Entry Point 'GetDeviceUniqueID' in a PInvoke DLL 'coredll.dll'.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong or haven't done that i was meant to ?